# how to add cc in email while sending email from iphone app

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, email

I am sending email from iphone app it is working fine i want to add cc also in email any idea how to do this .i am using following code can you please help how to add CC in this.

thanks.

initializing controller for sending email

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;


    NSString*giveFileName=@"CPAC_Contract_Equine";  
NSString *fileName;
//fileName = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@.pdf",giveFileName];
fileName = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",giveFileName];


NSString*myFileName=@"W9.pdf";


NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];


NSString *pdfFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];


NSMutableData *myPdfData = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfFile:pdfFileName];



NSString *pathJam = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"W9" ofType:@"pdf"]; 
NSData *myDataJam = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: pathJam]; 

NSArray * toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@""];


[picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];








[picker setSubject:@"CPAC Contract for Equine-Sam Veterinarian"];

[picker addAttachmentData:myPdfData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:giveFileName];




NSString * emailBody =@"<html><body>Thank you for your participation in Consulting<br>Practitioner and Client Program.</br><br>Attached is the copy of your signed contract for your records<p>Please email or fax your completed W-9 form to<br>our PEI Support Team<br>Email:PEISupportServices@zoetis.com<br>Fax:800-741-1310<body></html>";



[picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];





[self.navigationController presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: All you needed to do was look at the reference documentation for `MFMailComposeViewController` to answer this question. Also, there is no point to calling `setToRecipients:` with an empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MFMailComposeViewController has a `setCcRecipients:` method. You would use it like this:

```
[picker setCcRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"someone@example.com"]];
```

Comment: this will add recieptients what about cc

Comment: This does add CC. People who are CC'd still get the email, and therefore are recipients, but they are not To Recipients, who are to the email is to.

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSString *subject = @"";
    NSString *body = @"";
    NSString *address = @"to@gmail.com";
    NSString *cc = @"cc@gmail.com";
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"mailto:%@?cc=%@&subject=%@&body=%@", address, cc, subject, body];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[path stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[mailComposeViewController setToRecipients:@[@"ibanking@com"]];

[mailComposeViewController setCcRecipients:@[@"ccs.cmc@com"]];
```